# Weird error when calling static function

Tags: java

Code:

```
Config.setMain(new JavaPlugin());
```

and

```
public static void setMain(JavaPlugin plugin) {
    Config.plugin = plugin;
}
```

Errors: (both in `Config.setMain(new JavaPlugin());`)

> Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token

and

> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration

What am I doing wrong here? I don't understand.

```
package me.priv.project;

public class Te {

    Config.setMain(new JavaPlugin());

}
```

Comment: I cant believe that you show us the full code...

Comment: Where is the `Config.setMain(new JavaPlugin());` line located?

Comment: Added a class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config.setMain(new JavaPlugin());` must be called from some method, initializer block or constructor.

Since it's a static method and it initializes a static member, a static initializer block seems like a good candidate :

```
public class Config {
    ...
    static {
        Config.setMain(new JavaPlugin());
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you can get rid of that method and just write :

```
public class Config {
    static JavaPlugin plugin = new JavaPlugin();
}
```

Comment: "Cannot instantiate the type JavaPlugin"

Comment: That means your answer did not work.

Comment: @Priv Does the `JavaPlugin` class it have a public constructor that accepts no arguments? I was assuming it does, basted on your `new JavaPlugin()` statement.

Comment: It has, but I didn't write the JavaPlugin class myself.

Comment: @Priv Are you sure JavaPlugin is not an interface instead of a class? Or perhaps an abstract class? There must be a reason you can't instantiate it.

Comment: Abstract class.

Comment: @Priv In that case you can't create an instance of it. You should create an instance of one of its sub-classes instead (or call some factory method that will return an instance - perhaps JavaPlugin has a getInstance() static method).

Comment: When I have `public class Te extends JavaPlugin` I'd like to use `Config.setMain(this);` but then it gives that weird errors.

Comment: But why can't I call that method? I don't understand

Comment: @Priv As I said in my answer, you must call `Config.setMain` from a method,constructor or initializer block. That's one of your problems (you are trying to call in from the body of a class). The second problem is that you can't instantiate JavaPlugin.